# Retrieving id of a <li> element with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a problem retrieving an ID of a "li" element which I would use in AJAX.

```
<div id="subTab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="display:none" id="users">
        <li id="AUser"><a href="#AUser"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User Management</a></li>
        <li id="ARole"><a href="#ARole">Role Management</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With ajax using this code I add "active" class to the "li" element:

```
$(this).closest('ul li').addClass('active');
```

So my question is, how to retrieve the ID attribute of li that would have the active class in it?
I tried lots of ways, but none of them were successful..

```
$('#subTab').find('li .active').attr('id');
```

this one returns nothing.

```
$('#subTab').find('ul li').closest('.active').attr('id');
```

this one returns the "ul" elements id..

If anyone has a solution, please help me solve this,
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the space here. When you're using space, the selector will match the descendants with class `active` of your `li` elements instead:

```
$('#subTab').find('li.active').attr('id');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HyAv2/)**

Comment: Thank you a lot! I figured out a similar solution after a while - $('#subTab').find('.active').closest('li').attr('id'); but i might use yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

The short way:

```
$('#subTab li.active').attr('id')
```

In action: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcurbelop/63PK6/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a space in the selector. A space is used for selecting descendants, what you're asking for is to find an element with class `active` that is a descendant of an `li`.

Remove the space:

```
$('#subTab').find('li.active').attr('id');
```

Now it's asking for elements that are a `<li>` and have class `active`.

From [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

> A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by white space. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A

Answer (score 0):

use .each because 'active' class apply to more than one li.

```
$("#subTab").find('ul li').addClass('active');
$("#subTab").find('li.active').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```